# Iterate over a few objects in a single loop?

Tags: apex, sobject

I have a few objects that have the same fields (referring to Article Types) such as: FAQ__kav, Tutorial__kav, Video__Kav

Is it possible to add all of these records to a single list (I guess of type Sobject) and then iterate over it? If so, what's the correct syntax?

Hoping to find something like this:

```
Faq__kav record1;
Tutorial__kav record2;
Video__kav record 3;

List<Sobject> kbList = new List<Sobject>();

kbliist.add(record1);
kblist.add(record2);

for(Sobject record : kbList){
  if(Sobject is type of FAQ__kav)
     do something...
  else if (Sobject is type of Tutorial__kav)
     do something else
```

Comment: yes, we can iterate in this way.

Comment: tnx @PragatiJain, what's the name of the method to distinguish between sobjects? (if Sobject is type of...)

Comment: Use `getSObjectType()` method of `SObject` class (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this dynamic access technique (all SObjects support [map-like methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm_)):

```
for (Sobject record : kbList) {
    String stringField = (String) record.get('StringFieldApiName');
    ...
}
```

to avoid the type-specific if/elseif/else coding for the common fields.

If you do need type-specific logic, the relatively new [switch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm) is a good way to do that:

```
for (Sobject record : kbList) {
    switch on record {
        when Faq__kav f {
            // f is a reference of type Faq__kav in this block
        }
        when Tutorial__kav t {
            // t is a reference of type Tutorial__kav in this block
        }
        when Video__kav v {
            // v is a reference of type Video__kav in this block
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that switch is available in Apex, thanks @Keith C!

Comment: @Json Yeah it's fairly new so you don't see many examples of it. Not sure if the class API version needs to be set to the latest or not - best to do that anyway if it is new code.